# Grub selection screen

Tags: grub2

We have multiple arcade games that use the Linux/Ubuntu software. Recently (Last 10 months) when turning on our machines, this menu started coming up & I am not sure why. Some times the counter (Bottom right) counts down & selects the highlighted choice & sometimes it freezes on 29 seconds. These machines are out on location so we will have to go to each one to force it through with a keyboard only for it to happen again a few days later. Any help as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated (Pics attached for reference)[Grub selection screen Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REchh.jpg)

Comment: Looks like standard grub menu. What are your grub settings? Post in question above.  `cat /etc/default/grub` I do not recommend timeout be 0 as then you have no time to get to grub menu if required. But I do change from default of 10 sec to about 3 sec.

Comment: I am not sure how to find that out. We would never see this menu when booting up the machine/Game. They would just boot straight to the game. I have never seen this until it started doing it earlier this year. Is there a way I can get it back to not seeing the menu or is there a reason it has started popping up?

Comment: Grub sets  a flag on boot, and if you have an abnormal shutdown that does not clear flag, it will see flag on reboot and show menu. Then you can boot recovery mode. Is shutdown normal? If only one install, menu should not normally be shown and it just boot one install, unless you use key to show menu. One user had book next to keyboard holding key down that caused menu to show.

Comment: Shutdown is normal. Sometimes machines will reboot themselves (normal function) but otherwise shutdown is normal. These games are out on location & do not use a keyboard unless we have to diagnose which then we will plug one in. I can turn of the cabinet power supply (Separate from the computer power supply) and turn it on 10 second later & it will show the grub menu.